# Graphical comparison tool to use with svn on Mac OS 10.7

Tags: macos, software-rec, diff

Is it possible to view "svn diff" output graphically on Mac OS?

Most of the graphical diff programs allow you to view only one file per time. Which is very inconvenient when you use svn and have changed like 10 files.

For Linux I have found a solution in "[kompare](http://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/kompare-a-tool-of-beauty/)" program.
So I do:

```
svn diff > diffOut;
kompare diffOut
```

and as result I work with graphical program and check all files at once like it shown on the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soFmh.jpg).

**Is there same free tool for Mac OS?**

P.S. I know about [similar topic](https://superuser.com/questions/31130/what-is-the-best-file-comparison-directory-comparison-tool-for-mac-os-x), but

1. I can't check meld because it is not installing for me (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/460772/meld-on-os-x-10-7-doesnt-work)).
2. I checked KDiff3, FileMerge opens only one file from all.
3. I don't want to install all of the proposed there tools to check which one is appropriate for my more specific problem. And it is not usually clearly written in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check ECMerge (I work for Ellié Computing), it has a "patch preview" mode which does something similar to what Kompare does. You have to open the folder in ECMerge then run the Patch Import and ask for a preview, it opens a 2-way merge of the original folder with a temporarily applied version, you can then review what changed (changed items are bookmarked).

Comment: It is not free?

Comment: oops, no it is not. I missed that in the body of your question. It is not expensive but not free.